# Here-api: REST geolocation api request change

Tags: rest, geolocation, here-api

Trying the Here geolocation api with wlan data, originally the json request body was an array of {mac, powrx} objects. Mac being the mac address of the WiFi AP, powrx being the RSSI received for the beacon frame.

Recently, I've noticed the powrx parameter is no more mentioned in the documentation (although accepted by the api).

Is the "powrx" parameter officially deprecated? Does it mean that the geolocation algorithm doesn't use this information (anymore) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to "Positioning API" in HERE REST APIs (https://developer.here.com/develop/rest-apis)

I checked the documentation in:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/topics_api/definition-wlan-locate.html
and it still mentions powrx.

There are no plans to deprecate this or other Positioning API parameters. If any parameter should for some reason be deprecated, there will be a prior notice in the documentation (see for example parameter 'frequency' in https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/topics_api/definition-cell-cdma-nmr.html).

Comment: Thanks, it is still indeed in the reference documentation although never used in any example in other part of the doc (quick start, guide, examples)